# How do I remove gray/white BackColor of RichTextBox when Disabled?

Tags: c#, winforms, disabled-control

I have a `RichTextBox` which I need to use as a Label for `RichTextBox`'s have background selection which I need for my Windows Forms Application.

I have encountered a problem when disabling the `RichTextBox`, it has made the `BackColor` of the `RichTextBox` to a whitish/Grayish.
I have tried using the following code:

```
ll.ForeColor = Color.LightGreen;
ll.Location = new Point(1, Form1.ActiveForm.Size.Height / 23 * 23);
ll.AutoSize = true;
ll.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
ll.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
ll.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
ll.Multiline = false;
ll.ReadOnly = true;
ll.Enabled = false;
ll.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;
ll.SelectAll();
ll.Font = new Font("ModeSeven", 12);
```

But still I get this... https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIGHv.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've just used the `readOnly` and not set the `Enabled` property as well property and got this:

[image]

which is exactly what you want i think.

here is the full code

```
     this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 12);
     this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
     this.richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
     this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 96);
     this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
     this.richTextBox1.Text = "tsglksklsmkld";
     richTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.LightGreen;
     richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
     richTextBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
     richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
     richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;
     richTextBox1.Font = new Font("ModeSeven", 12);
     richTextBox1.Multiline = false;
```

if you want it to also not be selectable you can do:

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.richTextBox1_SelectionChanged);
```

and in the handler:

```
  private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     richTextBox1.Select(0,0);
  }
```

Comment: I don't wont the RichTextBox to be select-able or editable, just like a Label. That is why I had Disabled the Enabled feature.

Comment: the way you delesect still shows the cursor. a better solution is to prevent the focus. like this: assign the Enter event `void richTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) { SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true); }` and also set the cursor: `richTextBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Default;`

Comment: Oh, I need to use the selection in the program I'm writing... your code blocks it from being used...

Comment: There is also one other problem, I need to use the KeyPress event and when I select the richTextBox I can no longer grab KeyPress from the Form.

Comment: @DanielJones if you want your not-selectable RichTextBox to be selectable, then you have a problem... either it's selectable, or not. can't be both

Comment: I don't wont the richTextBox to be selectable at all, not one bit, I just need it to display text, that's all.

Comment: @DanielJones well, the code i gave you shows text and not letting the user select it. as for the KeyPress, that's the way it works. when a key pressed on a control, that control and none other get the key press. you can, on the GotFocus event, to change the focus to the next control in order to prevent it

Comment: I've tried focusing on the Form when the RichTextBox is clicked but I get an error.

Comment: @DanielJones i used the Enter event and did on some other control .Focus() and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Windows comes with themes and when you disable a control on a form, the control will show its status according to the current theme.
You cannot change how a disabled control looks like, for it will always behave according to the current theme.

What you can do, though, is to create a custom control, inherit from RTB and define your `Paint`-event accordingly.

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/da514ec8-8834-4380-a302-f3c18325c9cc/changing-disabled-controls-forecolor) for a thread.